# Publishing tweets from wordpress

Tags: plugins, twitter

Is there any existing plugin that will tweet all posts from a category and/or with a specific tag?

I do *not* want something that publishes everything I'm editing or posting. I just wan't to be able to create a set of tweets (in form of posts) to be published when the post itself is published.

I need to have full control over the content that's sent to twitter which means no magic rewrites of the content.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Twitter Tools](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twitter-tools/) offers most of what you ask.

Whenever you post something, you can choose if Twitter Tools should post it to twitter or not. As far as I know, you can't tweet posts from a specific tag or category. But you do have control over which specific posts should be twitted.

Also, you have this "update tweets" thing, which I haven't tried, but sounds like you can make it check for older posts which should be twitted and twit them.

You can also make it do an automatic post with a digest of your tweets. Hope this helps!

Comment: There was a plugin I used a while ago that did what he wants, but I can't remember the name of it. :/ It basically auto-tweets new posts to the twitter account you setup. Very simple. I don't recall it auto-updating old tweets or re-tweeting updates to posts I made though.

Comment: Either I'm dumb or the plugin doesn't support this.